# Segfault trying to copy array from main memory to shared memory

Tags: c, operating-system

```
  int shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int)*sizeof(arr), 0666|IPC_CREAT);
  int* shm = (int*) shmat(shmid, (void*)0, 0);

  for(int i=0; i<1; i++){
    *(shm+i) = arr[i];
  }
```

Hi, I'm trying to copy an array from main memory into shared memory. I've been stuck for over 2 hours and can't figure out why this segment of code causes a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error.

Comment: Why aren't you testing for error from shmget?

Comment: What are the return values of `shmget` and `shmat`?

Comment: `sizeof(int)*sizeof(arr)` is highly suspect.  Depending on how `arr` is declared, it might evaluate to either more or less memory than you actually need for all elements of `arr`, but it is unlikely to evaluate to exactly the needed amount.

Comment: @stark how do I check for error from shmget? It returns a valid memory identifier I think (11940586501)

Comment: @WernerHenze shmat returns 1940848648, shmat returns 418091008

Comment: Please add the definition of arr.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is in writing to the shared memory and not in reading arr? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Mike729, `shmget()` returns -1 on failure, and `shmat()` returns `(void *) -1` on failure.  You should check for these to test whether the functions succeeded.  These details are covered in the functions' documentation.